# Cannot display a video created with FFMPEG from HTML

Tags: ffmpeg, video, python, html

I am trying to write Python code which will call ffmpeg via subprocess package and generate a video (.mp4) which was created by inserting multiple audio clips (.wav) at different time points.

```
temporary_output_path = "./output_0.mp4"
command_line = [
    "ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "./Output.mp4", "-i", first_video_output_path,
    "-map", "0:0", "-map", "1:0", "-c:v", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-async", "1", temporary_output_path
]
subprocess.run(command_line)

cnt = 0
for k, v in audio_time_dict.items():    
    command_line = [
        "ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "output_"+str(cnt) +".mp4", "-i", k,
        "-filter_complex", f"[1:a] adelay={v}|{v} [tmp];[0:a][tmp] amix=inputs=2,volume=3[audio_out]",
        "-map", "0:v", "-map", "[audio_out]", "output_" + str(cnt+1) + ".mp4"
    ]
    subprocess.run(command_line)
    cnt +=1
```

The video is generated successfully, and it can be played via VLC player, but when I try to insert it into HTML tag, as follows:

```
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <div
              className="tour__content"
              data-aos="fade-up"
              data-aos-duration="600">
              <video muted loop autoPlay controls>
                <source src="/images/video/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I get the following error:

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong? What could be the reason why the video is NOT supported?

Comment: I would start troubleshooting by first determining whether the browser itself doesn't like the file, or some aspect of the framework (aos along with whatever is hosting the page at `localhost:3000`) isn't working well with it. This can be done by browsing the file itself within the browser. As well, you can use `ffprobe` to get information about the rendered file to determine whether or not it is (a) corrupt, or (b) encoded with a codec not supported by the browser.

Comment: What is the "pixel format" of the `demo.mp4`? Is it yuv420 or yuv444? Note that some browsers have an issue with yuv444 (while yuv444 is the default pixel format of FFmpeg). Maybe there is a missing `"-c:v", "copy"` in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks! This actually helped. It was yuv444, and I've converted it to yuv420! Can you post an answer so I can accept it? @Rotem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers have an issue playing video with yuv444 pixel format while yuv420 is widely supported.

We may add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` output argument for encoding the video with `yuv420p` pixel format ([yuv420](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) chroma subsampling).

Note that `yuv444p` is the default pixel format of FFmpeg (at least when using the default libx264 encoder).

We may check the pixel format of the video file using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool (the name of the property is "chroma subsampling").